# Автоматическое тестирование Notification в Android приложении

Tags: android, android-notification, android-testing

Хотелось бы узнать есть ли какой-то инструмент, позволяющий тестировать `Android`-приложение. В настоящий момент меня не интересует тестирование `GUI`. Мне хотелось бы, чтобы машина вместо меня меняла дату на устройстве (или в эмуляторе), и далее сравнивала выведенные уведомления с эталонными (сравнение по названию и тексту).